# Backward kill in R session in emacs

Tags: r, emacs, dot-emacs

I have one more question about customizing emacs for use with an R session. I like to use the backward kill function, but this deletes the command prompt in the R session. I have tried modifying the function

```
 ;; Kill to the start of the command line for R
 (defun backward-kill-r ()
   "Kill chars backward until encountering the end of a line."
   (interactive)
   (delete-region (point-at-bol) (point)))
```

But I get the same prompt-deleting behavior. I'm guessing that I can change `point-at-bol` to correct this, but what do I need to change it to? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-c C-u` does what you want already. I find `C-a C-k` to be the easiest way to do this though, as I use `C-a` (move to the beginning of the line, which does the right thing in iESS mode) and `C-k` (kill line) are part of my emacs 'muscle-memory'.

FYI, instead of `point-at-bol` you want `comint-bol`, which will give you the behaviour you're after, if you don't want to use either of the suggestions above.